# Google Cloud function accessing a secret from Secrets Manger

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcp-secrets-manager

I'm having issues getting a cloud function to access a secret from the secrets manager. Basically I want to have my front-end access secrets by sending a request to the backend and then the backend getting the secret from secrets manager.

My cloud function endpoint looks like this:

```
Endpoint.get("/get-key", authMiddleware, async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    });

    const project = req.params.projectId;
    const secret = req.params.secret;
    const name = `projects/${project}/secrets/${secret}/versions/latest`;
    const credentials = await auth.getCredentials();

    const ver = new SecretManagerServiceClient({credentials,projectId:project});
    const request = {
      name,
    };
    const response = await ver.accessSecretVersion(request);
    const payload = response.payload.data.toString();
    console.log(`Payload: ${payload}`);
    return res.status(200).send({ payload });
  } catch (error:any) {
    console.log("get key error: ", error);
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

When I try to access that endpoint I get this error:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied: Consumer 'project:undefined' has been suspended
```

I tried explicitly setting the projectId there and it still gives me that error. Not sure what else I can change. perhaps the "latest" is not a valid endpoint for the secrets manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied: Consumer 'project:undefined' has been suspended
```

The above error occurs when you exceed usage quota as discussed in this [github thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/issues/58) or due to [ToS](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines) violations. You may need to submit the appeal. You can contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/getting-support) for the same.

Also make sure you have given [secretAccessor](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control#secretmanager.secretAccessor) role to your service account.

Comment: this did not solve my issue. I ended up avoiding using Secrets Manager. I believe the issue has to do with service accounts being different between the secrets manager and the function however I don't have time to go through it all.